# Make ActionBar vertical

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to achieve something like

[image: this]

and when the burger menu is clicked it will slide to right and shows the menus. Is there a way to achieve it? The default `ActionBar` is always horizontal, and I can't find any example to do it. 
Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: that's navigation drawer https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: the navigation drawer is the one that slide and an ActionBar is the one that has the burger menu? Am I correct? sorry I'm a bit confuse.